# Saving fields in a drop-down in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, php

Below is code that successfully displays a drop-down menu of page templates in my Wordpress theme. I'm using this menu in a custom post type, and don't quite understand how to label it in order to make it save the chosen value after the user "updates".

The value is, in fact, being saved to the database and displaying correctly to the table, it's just not maintaining the chosen value after update.

I've seen some other examples of this, but my drop-down is based on a PHP function all in one line. Any suggestions would be great appreciated.

```
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template"><?php _e('Page Template') ?></label>

<select name="page_template" id="page_template">

<option value='page_template'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
<?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>
</select>
```

HERE IS THE UPDATED CALLBACK FUNCTION THAT IS SUPPOSED TO DISPLAY THE DROPDOWN:

```
 // The Callback for Page Template Assignmets Metabox 
function pagetemplate() { 
global $post; 
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pagetemplatemeta_noncename" id="pagetemplate_noncename" value="' . 
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />'; 
// Get the title data if its already been entered 
?>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template"><?php _e('Page Template') ?></label> 
<select name="page_template" id="page_template"> 
<option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option> 
<?php template_dropdown($template); ?> 
</select> 

<?php

} 


//Creates the page template dropdown menu display and functionality
function template_dropdown( $default = '' ) { 
$templates = get_page_templates(); 
ksort( $templates ); 
foreach (array_keys( $templates ) as $template ) 
    : if ( $default == $templates[$template] ) 
        $selected = " selected='selected'"; 
    else 
        $selected = ''; 
echo "\n\t<option value='".$templates[$template]."' $selected>$template</option>"; 
endforeach; 
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$template`?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I updated the code based on the answer below, but still having problems. Apparently using the core code from WP is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code from the [WordPress core code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php) - line 580:

```
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template"><?php _e('Page Template') ?></label>
<select name="page_template" id="page_template">
    <option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
    <?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>
</select>
```

The only thing different from your code is `<option value='default'>`. So I don't think your code is the problem.

Also the [code for page_template_dropdown](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/template.php) isn't complicated:

```
function page_template_dropdown( $default = '' ) {
    $templates = get_page_templates();
    ksort( $templates );
    foreach (array_keys( $templates ) as $template )
        : if ( $default == $templates[$template] )
            $selected = " selected='selected'";
        else
            $selected = '';
    echo "\n\t<option value='".$templates[$template]."' $selected>$template</option>";
    endforeach;
}
```

So I'd hazard a guess that there's something wrong with your `$template` variable.

Comment: Yeah I've been studying both of those pieces of code. I don't really understand how they work together. I've added the function to my functions.php file, and nothing changed. Also, for saving the selection, am I supposed to use `page_template` or `default` as my label later on when I use this code to save the data: `$events_meta['page_template'] = $_POST['page_template'];`

Comment: I added the newest update to my functions.php for you to see. Again, I'm getting the dropdown to display properly and even post to the table, but it's not holding its value when saved by the user.

Comment: If as you say your default template gets updated in the database correctly - then when you refresh the page then you should have the text of the selected template in the `$template` variable. Have you tried printing out the $template variable to see what's in it?

Comment: Also, in the database, the DB updates based on "page_template" label, not the $template variable. But the drop-down does, in fact, change based on the $template variable.  I could post my full functions file for you - since I'm testing it only has this custom post type functionality within it, so not messy

Comment: `$events_meta['page_template'] = $_POST['page_template'];`

Comment: `foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) {  
    if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return;  
    $value = implode(',', (array)$value);  
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { 
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value); 
    } else { 
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value); 
    } 
    if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); } 
} 
add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2);`

Comment: icc97, I re-inserted some other example code from another tutorial and it appears that my problem is in saving the dropdown item, not the dropdown code itself. Once I clean up the saving part of it, I should be able to use the original functions we discussed.  Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

The code, it would seem works fine. You originally used:

```
   page_template_dropdown($template);
```

which is perfectly valid. But `$template` is supposed to contain the current posts' template. But nowhere do you set it to be so. In the core code, above the drop-down, they have:

```
   $template = !empty($post->page_template) ? $post->page_template : false;
```

which does this. How you retrieve the current posts' template will depend on how you've stored it.

Also, I would use `page_template_dropdown` rather than your own-defined, but identical function `template_dropdown` (reduces code duplication :) )

#### Side note:

In your metabox callback, `pagetemplate`, you do:

```
function pagetemplate(){
   global $post;
    ....
}
```

It would be better to use the fact that the `$post` object is passed as an argument:

```
function pagetemplate( $post ){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the help. I definitely need to clean some things up in my code. I still think there's an issue with the option not saving to the `selected` value upon the update. So I'm guessing somehow the `$selected` value is not being utilized correctly. Maybe I'm way off, but this would be the only thing stopping the dropdown from reverting to the value after the update, right?

Comment: As @Stephen Harris says - you're not setting the $template value. Try putting this at the top of your function: `$template = $post->page_template;`

Comment: icc97, still no good, would you like to take a look at this for me (only if you have the time).  I've been working on this almost all day.

Comment: @RobMyrick - the template is produced by the `page_template_dropdown` and it selects which ever template is passed by `$template`. So you need to retrieve the current post's template. I don't know how you've saved the template, so I can't saw how. Post templates are supported out of the box for non-pages so I'm not surprised `$post->page_template` doesn't work. How are you saving the user's input?

Comment: @RobMyrick - I meant the *dropdown* is produced by.... and also I meant to say that post templates *aren't* supported out of the box for non-pages. It's late :)